# "pid X is not a child of this shell" error reported by wait after spawning more than 545 tasks when executing script in docker

Tags: bash, docker, wait, background-task

The following script is rather straightforward: it spawns `count` of tasks and then waits for them. If `count` is greater than 545 it runs fine when executed outside of docker container, but fails when executed inside. `wait` suddenly reports that the oldest task PID is unknown. Increasing `count` by one will cause `wait` to report the same error for yet another task and so on. Note that all the spawned tasks are indeed executed and exit properly.

`test.sh`

```
count=546
pids=()
for (( index=0; index < count; ++index ))
do
        sleep 2 &
        pid=${!}
        pids+=(${pid})
        #echo "spawned task #${index} PID ${pid}" 1>&2
done
echo "done spawning" 1>&2
sleep 5
for (( index=0; index < count; ++index ))
do
        pid=${pids[${index}]}
        wait ${pid}
        code=${?}
        if [[ 0 -eq ${code} ]]
        then
        :       #echo "reaped task #${index} PID ${pid}" 1>&2
        else
                echo "task #${index} PID ${pid} exited with code ${code}" 1>&2
                #exit ${code}
        fi
done
echo "done reaping" 1>&2
exit 0
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
COPY test.sh /
RUN bash /test.sh
```

`docker build --no-cache "${PWD}"`

> done spawning
>   test.sh: line 15: wait: pid 8 is not a child of this shell
>   task #0 PID 8 exited with code 127
>   done reaping

[online compiler](https://repl.it/repls/FriendlyComplicatedAdaware)

Both host and container are using ubuntu:18.04, bash 4.4, docker 18.09.2 or 19.03.6 (tried on different systems).

Since problem occurs only after that oddly specific amount of spawned tasks i suspect that it must be hitting some sort of implicit limit on something. Bash manual even lists `CHILD_MAX` environment variable as such a limit, however setting it to large value by running script like `CHILD_MAX=8190 bash ./test.sh` changes nothing. Moreover, adding `jobs -l 2>&1` before / after `sleep 5` shows that all the spawned tasks are properly acknowledged, they have correct PIDs and statuses listed (though even more tasks will be reported by `wait` as not belonging to the current shell). I've also tried checking some potentially related limits as well, but all of them seem to be not even close (`getconf -a | grep CHILD_MAX` yields 128275, `cat "/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max" 1>&2` yields 32768). Any ideas on what is going on here and how can this be fixed?

Comment: I get similar issues just copy/pasting into my MSYS2 environment running `BASH_VERSION=4.4.12(1)-release`. Not all processes produce this err msg chain :`bash: wait: pid 128424 is not a child of this shell
task #0 PID 128424 exited with code 127
bash: wait: pid 126960 is not a child of this shell;
task #7 PID 126960 exited with code 127;` and ~20 lines of similar output ending with `bash: wait: pid 132188 is not a child of this shell
task #30 PID 132188 exited with code 127
bash: wait: pid 132280 is not a child of this shell;
task #33 PID 132280 exited with code 127` . Good luck?! ;-)

Comment: (I have added the `;` chars to indicate `\n` in the output.)

Comment: @shellter Does the problem go away after lowering `count`?

Comment: I changed it to 500, and got the same results when copy/paste. I kept it at 546 and pasted into a file, followed by `chmod +x testR.sh` and that worked as you described. Very clean. The only thing I can think is that `CHILD_MAX` is a compiled-in value, not something that can be set per-process. Have to go now. Good luck!

Comment: Argg,,, edit ... `CHILD_MAX` ..... **cannot be set** pre-process. ;-! (Is my recollection/guess).

Comment: I don't understand why this got downvoted. A clear set of code and problem description. Oh Well. ... Good luck.

Comment: If I increase `sleep 2` to `sleep 10`, I can create > 3600 background processes without hitting the error.