# Why does bash "forget" about my background processes?

Tags: bash

I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
pids=()
for i in $(seq 1 999); do
  sleep 1 &
  pids+=( "$!" )
done
for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
  wait "$pid"
done
```

I expect the following behavior:

- spin through the first loop
- wait about a second on the first pid
- spin through the second loop

Instead, I get this error:

```
./foo.sh: line 8: wait: pid 24752 is not a child of this shell
```

(repeated 171 times with different pids)

If I run the script with shorter loop (50 instead of 999), then I get no errors.

What's going on?

Edit: I am using GNU bash 4.4.23 on Windows.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working, but for what it's worth, `wait` with no arguments will wait for all child processes, and `wait -n` will wait for any child.

Comment: Can't be sure, but sounds like forking a thousand processes is taking more than a second, so the early ones are already done when you hit the corresponding wait.  You could check this with a longer sleep.  Since 50 works with 1 second, 20 seconds ought to work for a thousand.

Comment: It shouldn't matter how long the children take.

Comment: Added version info.  Switching to a 20s sleep creates a new error: `./foo.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable`, probably due to hitting a system limit.  I thought `wait` produced the return code of even completed jobs.  If I do `echo foo &` and `wait $!` then it works even with ~60s between commands.  So the fact that `sleep` has already completed shouldn't affect anything, right?

Comment: what do you exactly mean when you say "GNU bash 4.4.23 on Windows"? cygwin? windows subsystem for linux? or ...?

Comment: This looks like the same problem: ["pid X is not a child of this shell" error reported by wait after spawning more than 545 tasks when executing script in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61637874/4154375).  It doesn't appear to have been resolved.  It looks like running large numbers of background processes causes Bash to malfunction in some circumstances.

Comment: I see exactly the same problem when I run the code on Cygwin with Bash 4.4.12.

Comment: The code in the question works with Bash 5.1.16 on my Ubuntu 22.04 VM, but it fails with the `pid XXX is not a child of this shell` error if I increase the number of background processes from 999 to 5000.

Comment: Is this an interactive or noninteractive shell? (Does it have job control enabled?) -- you'll get more predictable behavior if this is in a script, not run in an interactive shell.

Comment: I can reproduce with `docker run -ti --rm bash:4` on archlinux and big enough number `5000`.  I can reproduce with `bash:5.0.18` but can't with `bash:5.1.0`. From https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/bash-5.1/CHANGES : `Make sure SIGCHLD is blocked in all cases where waitchld() is not called
   from a signal handler.` maybe

Comment: I can more consistently reproduce with `true &`. `docker run -ti --rm -v $PWD:/mnt:ro -w /mnt bash:5.0.18 bash -c 'pids=; for ((i=1;i<550;++i)); do true & pids+=" $!"; done; wait $pids'` is the shortest I come up with.

Comment: I am running this from a script (`foo.sh`).  Job control should be disabled, but I tried with both `set -m` and `set +m` and get the same error(s) both ways.  As for the how I'm running bash: I don't have WSL or Cygwin, this version of bash came with when I installed git (iirc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[POSIX says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_03_02):

> The implementation need not retain more than the {CHILD_MAX} most recent entries in its list of known process IDs in the current shell execution environment.

*{CHILD_MAX}* here refers to the maximum number of simultaneous processes allowed per user. You can get the value of this limit using the `getconf` utility:

```
$ getconf CHILD_MAX
13195
```

Bash stores the statuses of at most twice as that many exited background processes in a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), and says *not a child of this shell* when you call `wait` on the PID of an old one that's been overwritten. You can see how it's implemented [here](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/jobs.c?id=ec8113b9861375e4e17b3307372569d429dec814#n735).

Comment: This answer seems the most likely cause.  Interestingly, the number of errors I get isn't consistent.  My CHILD_MAX is 256, but I can run up to ~700 bg processes without errors.  Possibly this is due to the hash table where results are stored.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The way you might reasonably expect this to work, as it would if you wrote a similar program in most other languages, is:

1. `sleep` is executed in the background via a `fork`+`exec`.
2. At some point, `sleep` exits leaving behind a zombie.
3. That zombie remains in place, holding its PID, until its parent calls `wait` to retrieve its exit code.

However, shells such as bash actually do this a little differently. They proactively reap their zombie children and store their exit codes in memory so that they can deallocate the system resources those processes were using. Then when you `wait` the shell just hands you whatever value is stored in memory, but the zombie could be long gone by then.

Now, because all of these exit statuses are being stored in memory, there is a practical limit to how many background processes can exit without you calling `wait` before you've filled up all the memory you have available for this in the shell. I expect that you're hitting this limit somewhere in the several hundreds of processes in your environment, while other users manage to make it into the several thousands in theirs. Regardless, the outcome is the same - eventually there's nowhere to store information about your children and so that information is lost.

Comment: "Proactively reap their zombie children" -- true, _when job control is enabled_, which it isn't for scripts. (If the OP is testing this in their interactive shell, that would explain the problem).

Comment: I don't think job control is the deciding factor. I can write a C program that forks+execs into a `/bin/sleep 30` and watch its status go to Z in the process table until the program eventually ends, but with an equivalent bash script the sleep simply disappears from the process table even with the only set options being `hB`. (both cases use a `sleep 60` to keep the program alive after the inital sleep is backgrounded to observe the behavior of the children)

Comment: My experience also is that non-interactive shells, without job control enabled, proactively reap their zombie children.  In fact, I've found it to be tricky to get a bash program to create zombie processes.

Comment: Similar topics come up in [How can I reproduce zombie process with bash as PID1 in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37022611/how-can-i-reproduce-zombie-process-with-bash-as-pid1-in-docker).

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce on ArchLinux with `docker run -ti --rm bash:5.0.18 bash -c 'pids=; for ((i=1;i<550;++i)); do true & pids+=" $!"; done; wait $pids'` and any earlier. I can't reproduce with bash:5.1.0 .

> What's going on?

It looks like a bug in your version of Bash. There were a couple of improvements in jobs.c and wait.def in Bash:5.1 and `Make sure SIGCHLD is blocked in all cases where waitchld() is not called from a signal handler` is mentioned in the changelog. From the look of it, it looks like an issue with handling a SIGCHLD signal *while* already handling another SIGCHLD signal.

Comment: I agree that this is a Bash bug (upvoted), but I don't think that it is (fully) fixed even in Bash 5.1.  I can reproduce the error with 5000 background processes using Bash 5.1.16 on a Ubuntu 22.04 VM.  That (to address Charles Duffy's reasonable concerns) was with a non-interactive shell (`bash testprog`).